# Virtual Device not getting detected by android studio.

Tags: android

I have downloaded all related packages ( Google usb drivers and android auto API simulators). The debugging mode in phone is on but even then device manager shows no connected devices.

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: Xperia SP. Android 4.3

Answer (score 0):

Try a different usb port and if your using a hub don't, reboot device while connected to usb ...there is probably some drivers missing that haven't been detected and or installed properly.